# Differences Of Using 'this' Or Not In AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are 2 AJAX request below:

```
function sFunction(str) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "some.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
function sFunction(str) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "some.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Both are working, the only difference is whether using `this` to refer `xmlhttp` or not. In this particular case, my question is:

1. which one is more suitable ?
2. is there any situation whereby one is having advantage over the other in this ajax function?

Need some pro opinions. Thanks.

Comment: try doing `console.log(this === xmlhttp)` in the function

Comment: The handler of the `this` version can be reused for similar ajax requests.

Comment: @Thomas what do u mean multiple ajax requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, neither is really advantageous, as they both point to the same object.

One possible advantage of using `this` is you could reuse the function on multiple AJAX objects, like this.

```
function rsc() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}

xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp1.open("GET", "some.php?q="+str, true);
xmlhttp1.send();
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = rsc;

xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp2.open("GET", "some.php?q="+str, true);
xmlhttp2.send();
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = rsc;
```

You could maybe save a little memory and work this way, but it would be very minor in most cases.

Comment: Do u mean if I have 3 Ajax the I can put it this way?

Comment: I chage the targeted PHP page, is that what u mean?

Comment: @P.Lau Yep, you can set a different URL for each one.

Comment: Ok got it!, Thanks.